# Keychain shows valid profile but in xcode - it says profile is not valid

Tags: ios, iphone

After creating certificate in Apple developer account able to extract in keychain access and shows, valid certificate in private key pair but in xcode -> organiser it says profile is not valid so I am not able to create build.

Comment: it happened with me too. I spent half day resolving this but couldn't figure out the problem and then I had downloaded profiles and certificates again. It started working. Keep this as a last option if any thing doesn't work out.

Comment: How did the below answers work out, Hitendra?

Comment: Downvoted with regrets (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new provisioning profile (Distribution or Development depends on your need) and map that newly created certificate to that profile while creating. Then, Download and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are looking for the developer or distribution certificate in the "Login keychain". Look into "my certificates" for the certificate and check if the private and public key is associated with this certificate?

If above is fine, then please delete your old provisioning profile from organizer and create a new provisioning profile using the same certificate which is in Keychain from developer.apple.com

Please follow above steps and let me know if that works or not. If not then please write the further issue as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Quit and relaunch the Xcode. It may resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You seem confused between profiles and certificates. Profiles(Provisioning profiles) link up a developer/distribution certificate, device list, and a bundle id.

**Case1:**

It seems that you had a provisoning profile1 pointing to certificate1. Then you created profile2 which points to certificate2. Then you downloaded the profile2 and started using it for code signing missing out on downloading the certificate2 and adding it to key-chain access. So what is happening is xcode uses profile2 and from profile2 it tries to fetch certificate2 which you havent added yet, hence it shows a code signing error. Try downloading the certificate2 and add it to key chain.

**Case2:**

it may be the other way around you downloaded the certificate2 but did'nt edit the profile1 to point to certificate2 and the certificate1 might have expired.

Hope this solves the problem